# DHCP сервер отправляет DHCOFFER но там нет leased-addres

Tags: linux, debian, dhcp

Настроил DHCP сервер c option 82, но он оправляет офферы без адреса, не могу понять в чем причина. Хотя в логах пишет, что адрес присвоен. Сonf серевера:

```
default-lease-time 6000;
max-lease-time 72000;
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
log(info, "***");
if exists agent.circuit-id {
       log( info,concat("*Leased ",binary-to-ascii(10,8,".",leased-address)," (with opt82)") );
       log( info,concat("*Remote-ID: ",substring(option agent.remote-id,2,13)));
       log( info,concat("*Port: ",binary-to-ascii(10,8,"",suffix(option agent.circuit-id,1))) );
} else {
       log( info,concat("*Leased ",binary-to-ascii(10,8,".",leased-address)," (without opt82)") );
}
log(info, "***");
subnet 10.55.56.48 netmask 255.255.255.240{
       class "local" { match if (substring(option agent.remote-id,2,13)="10.55.56.49" and binary-to- 
                      ascii(10,8,"",suffix(option agent.circuit-id,1)) = "1");}
                     pool { range 10.55.56.52 10.55.56.55; allow members of "local"; }
       class "local2" { match if (substring(option agent.remote-id, 2, 13) = "10.55.56.49" and 
                       binary-to-ascii (10, 8, "", suffix( option agent.circuit-id, $
                       pool { range 10.55.56.56 10.55.56.62; allow members of "local2"; }
```

}